# Third party @font-face isn't working - not applying font to H1 tag

Tags: css

My `@font-face` tag in my CSS code does not work:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'vcr_osd_monoregular';
    src: url('https://rx-gkit.neocities.org/vcr_osd_mono_1.001-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('https://rx-gkit.neocities.org/vcr_osd_mono_1.001-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'vcr_osd_monoregular';
}
```

The code above defines a font, but it's not applied to the `h1` tags. Is there any reason why this isn't working?

It does not return an error, it just simply does not work. Am I doing something wrong?

[Site](https://rx-gkit.neocities.org/)

Comment: You shouldn’t hotlink other websites’ resources. Neocities is not a CDN. Host it yourself.

Comment: @dai I know that, but [this](https://rx-gkit.neocities.org) is my site, therefore I am granting myself permission to use it. (I am using my OWN site as a third party.)

Comment: Tested your site with Chrome and it seems to work. If I change the font-family value in the inspector, the font at least changes. Please explain in more detail how it should look like.

Comment: @christian it should be the VCR OSD MONO font ([looks like this](https://fontmeme.com/fonts/vcr-osd-mono-font/))

Comment: @rxgkit "using your own site as a third-party" - what you write doesn't make any sense. If it's your own website then consider using `//` instead of a FQDN.

Comment: @dai ok, thanks. I will try that

Comment: I am getting a (expected ?) CORS errors when running your code. Are you definitely serving the font in an open way? Do you not see any errors in your browser console? Are you on the same host?

Answer (score 0):

Are the fonts hosted in the root directory? Or are you linking to them from another site?

When fonts are hosted in a different domain (e.g., linked from `www.site.com` to `sub.site.com`), they are blocked and not applied for security reasons.

Comment: well, what if i do something like [example.org](https://www.example.org) to [example.net](https://example.net) or [other.example.net](https://other.example.net)

Comment: Well, that's not true at all. It depends on the font and how they are served by the server. Otherwise we wouldn't have services like Google Fonts.

Comment: @HereticMonkey In 5 years' time I'm going to re-register all of the domain-names used by dodgy JavaScript and font "CDN" services and XSS everyone. Or just post bright red flashing messages everywhere telling people to stop thinking CDNs will exist forever. I haven't decided yet.